# Tensorflow: run different function elementwise depending on True/False value of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

out = tf.constant([0, 1, 0])
ta = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
crct = tf.constant(tf.math.logical_and(tf.equal(out, ta), tf.equal(out, 0)))

def f_crct_1(): return tf.add(out, ta) #in case crct is True
def f_crct_0(): return tf.square(out)  #in case crct is False

res = tf.cond(crct , f_crct_1, f_crct_0)
#since crct = [ True, False, False]
#res = [0+0, 1**2, 0**2]
```

I get: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What I want to achieve is depending on crct run different function elementwise.
(I am new to tensorflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

out = tf.constant([0, 1, 0])
ta = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
crct = tf.reduce_all(tf.math.logical_and(tf.equal(out, ta), tf.equal(out, 0)))

def f_crct_1(): return tf.add(out, ta) #in case crct is True
def f_crct_0(): return tf.square(out)  #in case crct is False

res = tf.cond(crct , f_crct_1, f_crct_0)
```

tf.equal generates tensor of shape (3,1) not (1,1). You need to use reduce_all
Although your logic for crct is not true. Crct variable will be true only when both tensors become [0,0,0]

Comment: It works but I don't get it. 
According to your solution:
out = <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0])>
ta = <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2])>
crct = <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>

Above should be (as in original question): <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True, False, False])>

And finally gives:
res = <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0])>
which is correct - question is how from ctct of shape=() I get res of shape=(3,) ?

Comment: Based on your question, res will run f_crct_1 if crct is True which will be true given your condition & res will run f_crct_0 when crct is False.

Comment: Crct = <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True, False, False])> Is reduced to tensor of shape (1,) otherwise it won't be used as a condition. tf.cond is just like if statement. You can use tf.reduce_all or tf.reduce_any based on your requirement. tf.reduce_all will return True only when all elements are matched in condition tf.equal.

Comment: Actually I'am trying to convert this pandas code to tf: `import pandas as pd
res = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 0], columns=['out'])
res['ta'] = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2])
res['crct'] = 0
res.loc[(res['out'] == res['ta']) & (res['out'] == 0), 'crct'] = 1

def f_crct_d1(): return res['out'] + res['ta']
def f_crct_d0(): return res['out']**2

res.loc[res['crct'] == 1, 'win'] = f_crct_d1()
res.loc[res['crct'] == 0, 'win'] = f_crct_d0()
`

Comment: Result should be:
#   out  ta  crct  win
#0    0   0     1  0.0 if crct == 1 then run f_crct_d1() on this row
#1    1   1     0  1.0 if crct == 0 then run f_crct_d0() on this row
#2    0   2     0  0.0 if crct == 0 then run f_crct_d0() on this row

Comment: Redefine your tensors into shape (None,1) & then perform operations. Try studying vector algebra to clear the concept. Only, then you will be able to solve this problem.